# printing an hexademical but get an integer instead

Tags: python-3.x

Please can someone explain to me why print(0x18) displays 24?
I understand 0x18 is 24 in decimal but I expected output 0x18. Why did interpreter converted 0x18 to decimal?
In addition, print(str(0x18)) also displays 24. Please help me understand why?

Comment: you mean do to `print(0*18)` ?

Comment: `0x18` is an **`int` object literal**. It creates the **same exact** object as the decimal literal `24`. The default representation of *any* `int` object is decimal. Note, `int` objects are fundamentally represented in binary.

Comment: The most reasonable thing to do is to use [*string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) if you want your `int` object to be printed in a particular way. So `my_int = ... # whatever` then you can do `print(f"{my_int:x})` or `print(f"{my_int:#x}")` for a hexadecimal representation, or `print(f"{my_int:#o}")` for octal, etc etc

Comment: To put it another way, `0x18` doesn't mean "create a special type of integer which has an underlying, hexadecimal representation". It means "interpret this source code using hexidecimal to create the standard `int` type with that value".

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, default representation for integers is decimal. You can print the hexadecimal representation using `hex` function:

```
print(hex(0x18))
0x18
print(hex(24))
0x18
```